# SwiftUI stuck in updating view loop?

Tags: swiftui

I am building a view that uses WKWebView. To that end I am using `UIViewRepresentable`.

I would like to show the web page loading progress using a ProgressView. To that end I want to drive the progress UI using the `WKWebView.estimatedProgress`.

I am putting here the entire code. If you copy and paste this in a project you'll see that `TestWContainer` **is stuck updating**. I am trying to understand how to fix this, and I guess understanding the correct design pattern to follow in a situation like this to avoid endless view updates.

Here the code:

```
struct TestWContainer: View {
    
    @State var url:URL?
    @State var userSetUrl:URL?
    @State var showLoader:Bool?
    @State var estimatedProgress:Double?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            WebView(currentURL: $url, userSetURL: $userSetUrl, showLoader: $showLoader, estimatedProgress: $estimatedProgress)
            
            if let estimatedProgress = estimatedProgress {
                if estimatedProgress > 0 && estimatedProgress < 1 {
                    let _ = print("estimatedPogress: \(estimatedProgress)")
                    VStack(spacing:0) {
                        ProgressView(value: estimatedProgress, total: 1)
                            .frame(height: 3)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}





struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    
    @Binding var currentURL:URL?
    @Binding var userSetURL:URL?
    @Binding var showLoader:Bool?
    @Binding var estimatedProgress:Double?
    
    
    fileprivate let defaultURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
        var parent: WebView
        var webViewNavigationSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        
        init(_ webView: WebView) {
            self.parent = webView
        }
        
        deinit {
            webViewNavigationSubscriber?.cancel()
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.showLoader = false
        }
        
        func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
            
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            parent.showLoader = false
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.showLoader = true
        }
        
        // This function is essential for intercepting every navigation in the webview
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
        
        override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
            print("Observing keyPath: \(keyPath). change: \(change). object: \(object)")
            guard let wv = object as? WKWebView else { return }
            if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress) {
                print("O: progress: \(wv.estimatedProgress)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.estimatedProgress = wv.estimatedProgress
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        webView.addObserver(context.coordinator, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
        
        print("setup: \(currentURL)")
        load(url: userSetURL, in: webView)
    
        return webView
    }
    
    fileprivate func load(url:URL?, in webView:WKWebView) {
        
        if let url = url {
            print("load url....: \(url)")
            let req = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(req)
        } else {
            print("load url google case...")
            let req = URLRequest(url: defaultURL)
            webView.load(req)
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView: \(userSetURL)")
        load(url: userSetURL, in: webView)
    }
    
}
```

How can I change things so that I can drive a ProgressView with the built in WKWebView `estimatedProgress` property without getting stuck in a View update cycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a circular dependency -- you've defined `estimatedProgress` as `@State` and then sent it to the `WebView` as a `@Binding`. The `WebView` updates `estimatedProgress`, which then re-renders the view (since the state is updated). In `WebView`, you're calling `load` in `updateUIView` which is called every time the `WebView` re-renders with new input (ie one of its Bindings has changed).

The easiest fix is to just remove the `load` call from `updateUIView`. But, that would have the side effect of now updating the `WebView` in the case that you wanted to change the URL.

Another option is to store the state in an `ObservableObject` and *only* pass the trait that necessitates an update (I assume userSetURL) to the `WebView`:

```
class WebViewState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var url:URL?
    @Published var userSetUrl:URL?
    @Published var showLoader:Bool?
    @Published var estimatedProgress:Double?
}

struct TestWContainer: View {
    
    @StateObject var webViewState = WebViewState()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            WebView(webViewState : webViewState, userSetURL: webViewState.userSetUrl)
            
            if let estimatedProgress = webViewState.estimatedProgress {
                if estimatedProgress > 0 && estimatedProgress < 1 {
                    let _ = print("estimatedPogress: \(estimatedProgress)")
                    VStack(spacing:0) {
                        ProgressView(value: estimatedProgress, total: 1)
                            .frame(height: 3)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var webViewState : WebViewState
    var userSetURL: URL?
    
    fileprivate let defaultURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
        var parent: WebView
        var webViewNavigationSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        
        init(_ webView: WebView) {
            self.parent = webView
        }
        
        deinit {
            webViewNavigationSubscriber?.cancel()
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.webViewState.showLoader = false
        }
        
        func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
            
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            parent.webViewState.showLoader = false
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.webViewState.showLoader = true
        }
        
        // This function is essential for intercepting every navigation in the webview
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
        
        override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
            print("Observing keyPath: \(keyPath). change: \(change). object: \(object)")
            guard let wv = object as? WKWebView else { return }
            if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress) {
                print("O: progress: \(wv.estimatedProgress)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.parent.webViewState.estimatedProgress = wv.estimatedProgress
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        webView.addObserver(context.coordinator, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
        
        print("setup: \(webViewState.url)")
        load(url: userSetURL, in: webView)
    
        return webView
    }
    
    fileprivate func load(url:URL?, in webView:WKWebView) {
        
        if let url = url {
            print("load url....: \(url)")
            let req = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(req)
        } else {
            print("load url google case...")
            let req = URLRequest(url: defaultURL)
            webView.load(req)
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        print("updateUIView: \(userSetURL)")
        load(url: userSetURL, in: webView)
    }
    
}
```

You could also use a similar strategy with Combine to watch an updated property from within the WebView or it's coordinator, but that may be overkill for this situation.

Comment: Ok, I just tested your answer. Works great so I'll mark it as the answer. I am not clear on one thing. TestWContainer reacts to WebViewState. WebView sets webViewState.estimatedProgress as the observer kicks in... Why isn't that triggering TestWContainer View to redraw over and over again then?

Comment: It *is* causing `TestWContainer` to re-render (which is why the progress view updates), but not `WebView` because its input (`webViewState`, which is a reference type and `userSetURL`, which has not changed) don't change, so it doesn't need to update (and thus call `updateUIView` again). In general, in SwiftUI, as long as a view doesn't receive new inputs and its inputs are POD (plain old data), it won't trigger a re-render. You can also short-circuit this by using `.equatable` and specifying when it should update, but this should only be used in rare cases.